How to install lua-language-server on linux (Ubuntu)?
I'm trying to configure LSP in Neovim using lsp-config. I need to install lua-language-server to make the Lua LSP work, but I don't know how to install lua-language-server on Linux. The official documentation only shows how to install it for macOS and Windows.
Could you help me install it?
Ultimately, lua-language-server should be available in the terminal so that lsp-config can use it.

Did you see the plan B and C?

I tried to build from scratch (plan C) but it showed me errors and I stopped the installation :(

you can show what went wrong with building from scratch, if the target os is linux like, suppose it's fixable

I found another solution to do this. See my answer below. P.S. I didn't know that 'brew' could be installed on Linux because I primarily used it on Mac and made an assumption that it was a Mac-only tool.

it's an option too if it works as that supposed to be

The easiest way that I found is to use brew package manager.

Install Brew on Linux
Add Brew to $PATH. (It will be suggested at the end of the Brew installation. Just copy-paste)
Reload terminal to be able to use brew after setting the $PATH
Run brew install lua-language-server in terminal
Run lua-language-server (just to check if it is installed correctly)
Close lua-luangage-server (Ctrl + C)
Done


Here's the way for choosing "B. From latest release" from github.

Download the .gz file that meets your architecture.
I'd like to put the files to ~/.local/share/lua-lang-server. You can choose other place for them.

mkdir -p ~/.local/share/lua-lang-server && \
tar --extract --file <YOUR .gz FILE> -av -C ~/.local/share/lua-lang-server


Create a symbolic link in ~/.local/bin to the executable.

ln -s ~/.local/share/lua-lang-server/bin/lua-language-server ~/.local/bin/lua-language-server


Test if it works by executing lua-language-server.
(Optional) If step 4 fails since bash cannot find the executable lua-language-server, then you have to append ~/.local/bin to the environment variable PATH.

export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin

